# Fixed position pseudo-elements scrolling inconsistent across browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, background-image, css-position, pseudo-element

I've been trying to recreate a fixed position background effect with code from [this Four Kitchens blog post](https://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property), and running into inconsistencies between Safari, Chrome and Firefox. I have the following code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng021n4c/):

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.fixed {
    padding-bottom: 4em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
/*     transform: rotate(0); */
}
.fixed:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    will-change: transform;
}
.one:before {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/599');
}
.two:before {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/601');
}
.three:before {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/602');
}
.four:before {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/615');
}
.five:before {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/604');
}
```

In Chrome and Safari, the `.fixed:before` pseudo-elements seem to be positioned in relation to their `.fixed` parents (which themselves are `position: relative;`), but are scrolling in a fixed relation to the viewport. In Firefox, the pseudo-elements are all fixed position in relation to the viewport, so only the last one is visible.

If you uncomment `transform: rotate(0);` in Firefox or Chrome (like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p171dxL/)), the `.fixed` parent becomes a containing block ([per the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering)), and the images in effect become positioned absolutely. The effect of scrolling in relation to the viewport is lost, but there's no change in Safari.

`z-index` is coming into play as well, since the `z-index: 1;` on `.fixed` is critical in Safari and Chrome, and `z-index: -1;` on `.fixed:before` is necessary in Safari.

What's causing the images to scroll in relation to the viewport, but remain positioned in relation to their parent in Safari and Chrome? Is there any way to replicate Safari's rendering in Firefox?

Comment: Safari doesn't understand the `will-change` property, so it has no effect.

Comment: I've edited the question - I'm trying to figure out what exactly accounts for the rendering differences across Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, and `will-change` doesn't account for everything. Unless there's something specific that `will-change` is triggering (stacking context, containing block) that you can pinpoint?